# How to document this using jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I'd like to know how to document this type of class using `jsdoc`:

```
var MyObject = (function(){

  var that = {};

  function privateFunction(){};

  that.publicFunction = function(){};

  that.publicField = "foo";

  return that;

})();
```

Comment: What is `that.publicFunction(){};`?  Maybe you need an `=function` in there before the parentheses.

Comment: And why is an object with a `publicFunction` property and a `publicField` property considered a class?  Maybe there shouldn't be a `{}` at the end?

Comment: @Mike thanks for noticing the `publicFunction` stuff

Comment: @Mike actuall `MyClass` would be more like a singleton object. Not going to use it with the 'new' keyword to create instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things named JSDoc, but using [closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html) annotations which work with [jsdoc toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/), you can use `@constructor` to mark `MyClass` as a constructor.

```
/** @constructor */
var MyClass = ...;
```

Then you can make it clear that `that` is of the nominal type `MyClass` though obviously that nominal type won't work with `instanceof`.

```
/** @type MyClass */
var that = /** @type {MyClass} */ {};
```

The first `@type` establishes the type of the declaration, and the second is a type assertion/cast for the value.

With the methods you can use the `@this` annotation.

```
/** @this MyClass */
that.publicFunction = function () { ... };
```

Comment: +1 this is useful. I used bad terms acutally... `MyClass` is not going to be a class (not going to be used with the `new` keyword), I've changed it for `MyObject`

Comment: Is there a way to put the constructor under a namespace? I've tried using memberof but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @porlune, `my.namespace.MyClass = function ...`.